# Call one event from my Timer.Tick event

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

In my form I use the event `CustomDrawTimeCell` from my scheduler control but I need to execute that event every minute so I think I have to use a `Timer` control, my problem is **how can I call the event `CustomDrawTimeCell` from my `Timer.Tick` event?**

**EDIT**

This is what I need

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    'Call scheduler_CustomDrawTimeCell()
End Sub


Private Sub scheduler_CustomDrawTimeCell(sender As Object, e As CustomDrawObjectEventArgs) Handles scheduler.CustomDrawTimeCell
    'My code here
End Sub
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I raise the event in the control?" or "How do I call the handler in the containing form from another event?"

Comment: is CustomDrawTimeCell  is some method??

Comment: Show us you code! It is close to impossible to make anything out of a simple description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call handlers like any other subroutine...

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
  scheduler_CustomDrawTimeCell(scheduler, New CustomDrawObjectEventArgs)
End Sub
```

If you need to build that arguments object from something internal to the control, I suggest you add a method to the control to force it to build the argument and raise the event....

' in your control

```
Public Sub Force_Event()

 'build your argument
 RaiseEvent CustomDrawTimeCell(me, your_Arguments)
End Sub
```

'on your form

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
  scheduler.Force_Event()
End Sub
```

**However, you may want to think about putting the timer INSIDE the control instead and simply raising the event there.**